# Does php have any fixtures alternatives?

Tags: php, unit-testing, php-5.3

I have been working with Ruby on Rails for a while. It has a wonderful lib called factory_girl which helps a lot building a test data. Recently I have been searching for similar alternatives in PHP. The only library I came into was [Phactory](http://phactory.org).

I ask to share your experience on PHP testing data frameworks and recommend any handy libraries.

Comment: PHP is a language, RoR is a framework.
There are frameworks which provides you with fixtures such as CakePHP

Comment: What I am asking is to recommend some standalone PHP libraries, not frameworks

Comment: I'd bet that the `fatocry_girl` lib from RoR would not fit to the standalone Ruby (or for another Ruby framework)... The same here with libs for PHP frameworks... And it is impossible to create universal "fill-me-with-test-data" library that would work with everybody's code...

Comment: Actually it does. As I have already noticed there is a lib called Phactory. However it is not maintained a while. The reason of my question is to find out if there are any other patterns other than fixtures and factories because both of these I have already checked over internet

Comment: I don't think you'll find much. Unit testing in PHP is kind of terrible (at least that is my opinion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new fixture library called "[Alice](https://github.com/nelmio/alice)". It is not dependent on a framework, however you'd have to use either [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) or implement the `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager` interface. If you implement the ObjectManager interface yourself you don't need a database, you could just store the fixtures in memory.

You can read the fixtures from YAML or PHP files and there are provisions to create fixture ranges (User1, User2 ..User10), variable replacement, reference fixtures and generate data with the [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) library.

Answer (score -1):

Try https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker